# Python class objects and recalculating multiple attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, geometry, physics

I have had little experience with OO programming, being a typical engineer I tend to hack together functional code. However, I'm trying to change that and  I see value in implementing OO when modelling the physical world. I've written my first ever class for a [position vector](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)). I want an instance of the class to be able to store both the cartesian `[x, y, z]` and polar `[z, theta, phi]` coordinates of a position. Updating one attribute automatically updates the others. This class will be later be reused in other classes via composition.

I want an instance of my class to do the following:

```
>> p = PositionVector([15,5,5])
>> p.cartesian
[15,5,5]
>> p.polar
[16.583123951777, 0.0, 1.2645189576252271]
>> p.x = 3
>> p.cartesian
[3,5,5]
>> p.polar
[7.681145747868608, 0.7853981633974483, 0.8619682853367363]
>> p.theta = 0.5
>> p.cartesian
[5.117141702137862, 2.7955072527614058, 5.0]
>> p.polar
[7.681145747868608, 0.5, 0.8619682853367363]
```

The class I've written so far is below but with my limited understanding of python classes and the property function tells me there's a better way to do this. I don't know if the methods for *x y z r theta* and *phi* need to be fully written since they are simply elements within each list/array but can't figure out how to get around this. I also don't know if this is the safest and most pythonic way of structuring a class object:

```
class PositionVector(object):
  def __init__(self, vector, system='cartesian'):
    if system == 'cartesian':
      self.cartesian = vector
      self.polar = self.position_vector_polar(self.cartesian)
    if system == 'polar':
      self.polar = vector
      self.cartesian = self.position_vector_cartesian(self.polar)

  @property
  def cartesian(self):
    return self._cartesian
  @cartesian.setter
  def cartesian(self, value):
    self._cartesian = value
    self._polar = self.position_vector_polar(self._cartesian)
    self._x, self._y, self._z = self._cartesian
    self._r, self._theta, self._phi = self._polar

  @property
  def polar(self):
    return self._polar
  @polar.setter
  def polar(self, value):
    self._polar = value
    self._cartesian  = self.position_vector_cartesian(self._polar)
    self._x, self._y, self._z = self.cartesian
    self._r, self._theta, self._phi = self.polar

  @property
  def x(self):
    return self._x
  @x.setter
  def x(self, value):
    self._x = value
    self._cartesian[0]  = self._x
    self._polar = self.position_vector_polar(self._cartesian)

  # repeat above for y and z variables

  @property
  def r(self):
    return self._r
  @r.setter
  def r(self, value):
    self._r = value
    self._polar[0]  = self._r
    self._cartesian = self.position_vector_cartesian(self._polar)

  # repeat above for thets and phi variables

  def position_vector_cartesian(self, polar):
    r, theta, phi = polar
    x = r * math.cos(theta) * math.sin(phi)
    y = r * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi)
    z = r * math.cos(phi)
    return [x, y, z]

  def position_vector_polar(self, cartesian):
    x, y, z = cartesian
    r = math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)
    theta = math.atan(y/x)
    phi = math.acos(z/r)
    return [r, theta, phi]
```

Note that the lists will be be replaced with numpy arrays so i can perform algebra on the vectors but for now i just want to get the class structure correct.

Appreciate your help.

Clive

Comment: What is wrong with what you have written?  Have you tried to test it?  What are the test cases?

Comment: First, polar/cartesian are def as @property, but also in init. Second, I think you want to hack __setattr__/__getattr__ to have inplace conversion. Don't do that: write a function like in init, and update/get values from there

Comment: If it works, use it till you have a problem.  does it contain all the functionality you need?  ```polar``` and ```cartesian``` are properties with *setter's*, you don't need ```self.polar = self.position_vector_polar(self.cartesian)``` or ```self.cartesian = self.position_vector_cartesian(self.polar)``` in ```__init__```.

Comment: Maybe you'll be more successful in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? Check it out **:-)**

Comment: @wwii, the test cases would be in the first block above.  They work as expected. The next test cases would be too replace the lists with np arrays and perform addition and subtraction on multiple instances.

Comment: @wwii, I didn't think I needed the two function calls inside init but didn't know how to set the two depending on the value of 'system' at instantiation

Comment: @cox, I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean instead of 'p.x = 5', I should use something like 'p.set_x (5)'

Comment: Thanks @BorrajaX, I've [reposted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71908/python-class-objects-and-recalculating-multiple-attributes) to Code Review